# Fazer o Scrolll voltar ao inicio

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiz um Scroll animado e não estou conseguindo fazer o scroll voltar ao início da página

```
<script>
$().ready(function(){
    var posicaoInicial = $('html').position().top;
    
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight
        }, 50000);
        
        <!-- Nesso ponto verificar se o scroll esta no final da página, caso esteja deverá ser feito o reload -->
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
            location.reload();
        }
        
        
});
```

Comment: `window.scrollTo(0, 0);`

Comment: Não funcionou, tenho a impressão da forma de verificar se já é o fim do scroll que está errado, ficou assim :

if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
 window.scrollTo(0, 0); 
}

Answer (score -2):

Tente isso, deve te ajudar em algo

```js
window.scroll({
  top: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
})
```